# Mongoose method find issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

Why should I call await 2 times, when I've already done await in the model function:

`async function model() { return await data.find({}, '-_id -__v') }`

If I `console.log await data.find({}, '-_id -__v')` in the model function, I will see the array with right data.

But in the controller function *model function* returns a *Promise* instead of just an array, so I should use await again:

```
async function controller(req, res) {
    return res.status(200).json(await model())
}
```

I can't understand why it works that way.

Please, help me figuring this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because when you use async keyword your function will ALWAYS return a promise so using async await can be tricky :P

also you don't need to use await in model() since you are returning data, so I suggest you to use

```
function model() { return data.find({}, '-_id -__v') }

async function controller(req, res) {
    return res.status(200).json(await model())
}
```

to explain a little bit more why you don't have to use await in the model() function, that's because data.find() is a promise so you just have to return it, if you use async await you donc return data you also return a promise so there is no need and this can be confusing